# Flip boolean values list of lists in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, boolean

Consider the list of lists:

```
list =[[False, True], [True, False], [ False, False]]
```

I would like to flip all the boolean values here and would like to get

```
flipped_list =[[True,False], [False,True], [True, True]]
```

I know I can loop through each list inside the list and do something like `[not i for i in child_list]` but I am looking for an efficient of doing it without calling a `for-loop`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
map(lambda l1: map(lambda x: not x, l1), list)
```

Answer (score 1):

A for loop might not be a very bad solution in this scenario.

However, here is one solution using list comprehensions

```
>>> nested_list = [[False, True], [True, False], [ False, False]]
>>> [[not x for x in list_of_bools] for list_of_bools in nested_list]
[[True, False], [False, True], [True, True]]
```

This is assuming that it is only a 2 level nesting.

Answer (score 0):

```
not_flipped_list = [[not pair[0], not pair[1]] for pair in flipped_list]
```

is the best I can tell you, assuming that the list is as you showed, comprised of some number of pairs of booleans.  You're going to have at least one for loop, and I'm just avoiding having another one by hard-coding the second list size in the comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is add a wrapper function/object for extracting the values. Then the function/object could keep track of wether or not to flip the value.

This would end up looking something like

```
vals [0][0] #True
setFlipCond(true) #Sets some variable keeping track of flipping
extractVal(0,0) #False
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demonstration of a solution using map

```
bash-3.2$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 29 2016, 14:57:54) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> l = [[False, True], [True, False], [False, False]]
>>> l
[[False, True], [True, False], [False, False]]

>>> map(lambda x:map(lambda y:not y, x),l)
[[True, False], [False, True], [True, True]]
>>>
```